# Why it works in Javascript but in Python dont?

Tags: javascript, python, loops, nested-loops, break

I made the same code in Python and JavaScript and in JS it works but in python dont

This surprises me because I'm learning javascript, python is the language I believe I know the most and I'm not able to do it

**Javascript**

```
var name = "kayque";
var lastname = "othon";

var x = -1;
for(var i=0;i<6;i++){
    process.stdout.write(name[i] + "");
    x++;
    for(x;x<5;){
        process.stdout.write(lastname[x] + "");
        break;
    }
}
```

**Python**

```
name = "kayque"
lastname = "othon"

for letters_name in range(len(name)):
    print(name[letters_name], end="")
    for letters_lastname in range(len(lastname)):
        print(lastname[letters_lastname], end="")
        break
    letters_lastname += 1
```

I want to solve this problem, I'm learning these languages but I don't understand why in JS it works, but in Python it doesn't...

Comment: What's the point of a loop with an unconditional `break`? The second `while` is essentially `if (x < 5)`

Comment: The python version doesn't have anything analogous to the `x` variable. So it always starts with `letters_lastname = 0`, instead of incrementing it each time through the outer loop.

Comment: in js `for(x;...)` uses a pre existing x ... in python `for x in list` starts at 0 each time ... it is a different "letters_lastname" than the one that you do `+= 1` with ... see variable name shadowing ... the equivelent in js would be `for (let x of [...Array(name.length)])`

Comment: The code is different.

1st, you are defining limits in Javascript (5 and 6), not in Python. Besides, when you iterate in Python you are starting always from the beginning and breaking, so it will always print "o". It doesn't make a sense to use a break in Python without any condition.

Comment: Those two snippets are not remotely the same... And you did not include any of the expected vs. actual output.

Comment: The question should probably focus on _what you want to achieve_ and how to do it with Python. Not in why Python doesn't do it as JavaScript –because these are not equivalent implementations of the same algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your inner loop has a break after the first iteration. That means, that what your code does right now is print o right after each character of your first name ("kayque") which is confirmed because if we run the code the output that we get is ("koaoyoqouoeo").
If you wanna do it in a similar way to javascript here is what gives us the correct answer:

```py
name = "kayque"
lastname = "othon"

x = -1
for i in range(0, 6, 1):
    print(name[i], end="")
    x += 1
    while x < 5:
        print(lastname[x], end="")
        break
```

Answer (score -1):

I found this to work for this case: `print(name[0]+''.join([i+v for i, v in zip(name[1:], lastname)]))` But for a case with both names having an even amount of characters, you can use the `zip()` function. Here is what it would look like : `print(''.join([i+v for i, v in zip(name, lastname)]))`